# Unable to use dpkg to uninstall dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to uninstall the package openssh-client using dpkg.  I also have the packages openssh-server and ssh-askpass-gnome installed and want to uninstall those as well.

Currently I have the command `dpkg -r openssh-client` but that gives an error message that says

> `openssh-server depends on opessh-client.
>
>   ssh-askpass-gnome depends on openssh-client however:
>
>   Package openssh-client is to be removed`
>
> `dpkg: error processing openssh-client (--remove)
>
>   dependency problems - not removing`

I want to remove all dependencies as well as openssh-client.  I've tried the -B flag (aka --auto-deconfigure) but it does nothing

Apt-get works, but sometimes requires input (even with -y) and that is not acceptable (running from a script).

(Ubuntu 8.04.3 server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for a command switch in the `dpkg` manual to remove dependencies.

FYI `--force` is probably *not* what you want.

Comment: I have and it seems to say that --auto-deconfigure is the correct argument to use, but it does nothing. If it is a bug I will report it, but it seemed more like I was doing something incorrectly. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?dpkg

Comment: FYI I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/494161

Comment: Yeah that definitely looks like a bug then. Congratulations on finding one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dependencies handled automatically when removing / purging packages, dpkg can be a pain.  Aptitude is the command you want.